# "people with IQ over 1000 are needed."

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can I say "people with IQ over 1000 are needed to overcome technological lag" even though people with IQ over 1000 don't exist and are impossible?

Comment: You can **say** it, and it would be heard as an extravagant way of saying 'people who are very intelligent are needed'. You can say all sorts of silly things.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Can you be my teacher?

Comment: We don't do private lessons on this site.

Comment: You can say numerically or logically impossible things and they are usually understood by listeners as being exaggeration for emphasis. If you said 'this task needs 150 percent effort from all team members', it would be heard as meaning 'maximum effort'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you.

Comment: Why would English be different in this regard from any other language spoken on the planet?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about the English language in particular.

Comment: correction: **people with an IQ over 120** or **People with IQs over 120**. Don't confuse meaning, logic and grammar. 120 or 150 is more logical than 1,000 because those numbers do exist in the IQ world.

Answer (score 2):

It is of course possible to talk about things that don't exist.  I can't imagine a language which could only discuss things that exist (how would you talk about things that might exist, or don't exist yet?)

Just because you say something, doesn't make it true.  Grammar doesn't make something real.  You can say "Unicorns have one horn", or "Unicorns are a vegetable".  You will have to ask the philosophers whether either of these sentences is true.  It's not a matter of English grammar.

You can use words figuratively, metaphorically or hyperbolically.  You can say "All the world is a stage." or "The trees were moaning" or "His IQ is 1000".  Metaphors and hyperbole work in English as they do in other languages: for impact or for emphasis.

In your example, I would understand it to mean "It is impossible to overcome the technological lag". Since people with a 1000 IQ don't exist.

Comment: Can I say "ice is melted" even though there's no ice and there's only melted ice which is water?

Comment: You'd probably say "The ice has melted." or "The ice melted". But try to avoid asking new question in comments.  English has a different grammar to your language, but fundamentally it is just as expressive.